# No module named ijson

Tags: python, json, parsing, tweets

I have a big json file of tweets(around 5GB). I am having memory error. So, I decided to parse the data. I found ijson package. I am having such an error:

```
import ijson
parser = ijson.parse(tweets_data_path )
tweets_data = []
f = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
objects = ijson.items(f, 'other_config.item')
for line in objects:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue
```

"No module named ijson"
I am fairly new to Python, I looked at the source file of the package. But I could bout quite get what the requirements are. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How did you install the `ijson` package?

Comment: `import ijson` Is that a typo? The module is called [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html)

Comment: @CoryKramer it's an iterative json parser than one might use in situations where data is too big to fit in memory.

Comment: @larsks Oh okay, first time I've heard of it (not that I'm a good reference for that stuff, I rarely use JSON for my job)

Comment: I installed through terminal  like install ijson. But apparently did not work..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ijson` is an external package that is not included with the regular python libraries. You need to install `ijson` yourself first. Look into using something like [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html) which is a package manager for python. Once installed you can install [`ijson`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/) through the terminal like this:

```
pip install ijson
```

Comment: I had only tried installing through the terminal. Upon your suggestion I tried with pip, too.  When I ran pip install ijson, I am having "invalid syntax error"

Comment: @Denis: It seems like you have successfully installed ijson with pip! The `invalid syntax error` is perhaps regarding the rest of your code. Please update your original question and please provide the error message you are seeing. The error message should tell you where and what the problem is.

Comment: @ Parham But the error message appears on the code line of "pip install ijson". I don't have any syntax error in the rest of the code.Is there any other way I can install the package, maybe other beck end requirements, too? Thanks again.

Comment: I see. Are you running this from inside python? You need to run it from a terminal. The link I provided lets you install pip which you can then use from a command-line prompt. Please provide the output you are receiving, it would help

Comment: Awesome :) Please accept my answer also if you feel like it properly addressed your issue.